# AChartEngine Save and restore the zoom and pan state of a chart

Tags: android, plot, zooming, achartengine, pan

I use AChartEngine 1.2 to develop an android App. In my app I plot four different range variables.

My app consits of two activities, an InputActivity (main page) and a PlotActivity (second page). The user enters the input parameters in the first page and calculate the output by pressing a button. Then he/she may choose a variable to plot and press a button to accomplish that. Pressing the back button gives him/her the opportunity to go back to the first page choose another variable to plot. All of these work fine in the App.

But here is the question: I appreciate the ability to save the pan and zoom state of a graph such that all subsequent plots are done with in the same state. Shouldn't be an impossible task at all.

Best regards, Ramin.

Comment: Do you want a permanent saving or just as the app lives? First option: use a SharedPreferences manager to save your variables to disk. Second option: use some static variables in a class and recall their values.

Comment: Hi and thank you very much for the response. Could you attach a simple example for the second option. I don't know which variables to save as well as which methods in the life cycle to use.

Comment: It's very simple. In your InputActivity declare a couple of (float, I presume? at least for Zoom, I guess it's a float) variables as **static** (that is the magic). Set them as you want here. In PlotActivity, you just use them as **InputActivity.zoomValue** (if the name of your zoom variable is zoomValue). That's pretty much about it. Oh, yes, you can not only read them, but also write them in PlotActivity.

Comment: To @Vyger: I'm not sure I quite understand what you are saying. I have some more questions and comments: 1) By zoom and pan state I actually mean the lower and upper limits of axes, so I think these four fields must be double. 2) Shouldn't the PlotActivity set these variables after the user has drawn his finger over the display to zoom and/or pan? 3) What about onSave, onResume, onPause and onStop Methods? Shouldn't they be used here? Could you provide a little sample for this? Thank you.

Comment: 1) Ok, I don't remember what aChartEngine uses for Zoom and Pan, (I'm going from memory) you're probably right. 2) Yes, set them in PlotActivity (but then, do you still need them in InputActivity?). 3) OnPause and OnResume are used for when you rotate the device, to retain the state.

Comment: To @Vyger. Thanks a lot. Your solution worked perfectly. I save the min and max of x-axis in two private static variables, because I don't need them in the InputActivity. This is done in onPause and used in onResume.

Comment: Glad to have contributed... ;)